# Push branch hangs and is stuck using Git extensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am working with git extensions for vm, it was all fine till i changed my pc.
In the new pc, the git cloning was taking lot of time, so what i did was

1. Copied the .git folder from my older pc
2. Loaded into the new c
3. opened in git extensions as a git repo
4. checked out the brnach i wanted to work on, and started working on it.

**Pulling the changes worked**, **the problem came when i wanted to push changes**,
The push dialog is open for hours and still it cannot push the branch, the commit changes were hardly 5 files

One additional information is that When I Remote -> Manage Remote repositories -> Test connection 
it gave the error message `"FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused "`.

Any suggestions ??

Related information:

1. Windows 7
2. Git extensions 2.4.6

Comment: you can get more info by running git with --verbose flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no no, you must **never** copy git folder,
It can cause many problems when copying from one machine to another, on the same machine so no problem You're trying to make a `push` with other credentials or any data that is in the cache `git`.

My advice is to delete the remote and reloading, but haslo from git bash.

Remove remote `git remote rm`

Add remote `git remote add`

To [read](http://gitref.org/remotes/).